# Calling Meteor from Native iOS Application

Tags: ios, meteor

We are building an application that consists of a web app and a **native** iOS client.  The web app is pretty straight forward with Meteor.  But on the Native iOS App was wondering if someone can give us some pointers on the best practices for that app to call into meteor.  I have seen that there is something like the collectionsapi api which exposes meteor collections over http, but am not sure how we would handle authentication for Native iOS clients if we used something like the collectionsapi or similar.  Any pointers from some folks who have done this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Meteor's communication system is based on [DDP](http://meteor.com/blog/2012/03/21/introducing-ddp) (Distributed Data Protocol). You can access meteor's methods & make subscriptions to data which is probably the best way to go since you can get live data back too!

There is an objective-c client but its not been maintained : https://github.com/alansikora/objective-c_ddp-client

The ddp client was originally made prior to an official ddp specification (pre1). So you would have to adjust the client a bit to bring it up to date. Luckily its not too much work. The full DDP spec can be found here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/livedata/DDP.md

Using DDP is a very attractive alternative to making a traditional REST request (POST,GET,PUT,etc). As the data on the wire is the same system meteor's client communicates to its server. So if you're able to make something on meteor work in a web browser you could pretty much replicate it on a native iOS client.

Answer (score 5):

If you are still wondering about this, I've been working on a free, open source project that enables native ios clients to do meteor auth (SRP auth) and communicate via DDP. The project lives here: https://github.com/boundsj/ObjectiveDDP

There is an example app here: https://github.com/boundsj/ObjectiveDDP/tree/master/Example